# Terraform anytrue condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've an instance type variable specified in *.tfvars and am trying to incorporate the use of the "anytrue" function however am unable to get it to work. The aim is to give users an option of four instance types and they are the only instance types to be accepted

```
variables.tf
variable "myinstance" {
    type = list(string)
    description "Select one of the following instance types - t3.medium, t3.large, t3.xlarge 
                 or t3.2xlarge"
    validation {
        condition = anytrue (["t3.medium","t3.large","t3.xlarge","t3.2xlarge"],var.myinstance)
        error_message = "Please select a valid instance type."
    }
    default = []
  }
```

*.tfvars file = ["t3.medium"]

error message:

```
     var.myinstance will be known only after apply.

     Function "anytrue" expects only 1 argument(s)
```

Comment: Use `contains(list, value)` instead - `anytrue` checks for true values only & not for any other value e.g. instance types

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary This will not work as `value` can't be list.

Comment: @Marcin Ah, it's a `list(string)` - you're right

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary But maybe OP wants only a single instance, as the msg writes " Select one .".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think th best way would be to use [setintersection](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setintersection):

```
 condition = length(setintersection(["t3.medium","t3.large","t3.xlarge","t3.2xlarge"], var.myinstance)) >= length(var.myinstance)
```